# CSS preview different on multiple browsers

Tags: html, css

This is happening to me while I am trying to learn web development.
I am only getting the expected result when I preview my website on IE old version, but not getting the expected result when opening on Firefox or Chrome.

Here is the code, it's a very simple one. It's supposed to change the color of the links when visited but what it's doing is that it is constantly applying `visited` properties to my text.

What I am trying to do is simply changing color of link while in `link` and `visited` state.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>    
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSworking.css">
        <title>Html Working</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <ul class="main">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Kitchen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Go Down</a></li>
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.main {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
.main li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
.main li a:link {
    color:pink;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: green;
}
a:hover {
    border-top: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Those are all the same URL, so they're all going to be "visited" once you click one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using '#' as the link for all of these, you're using the same (local) link for all of them, so if you've visited that local anchor once they'll all stay visited.

Can you try changing to external links such as 'http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', etc and see if the problem persists?